# Can WebOptimizer be used with Single-File Application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I'm currently unable to use the WebOptimizer with a single-file web-app (asp.net Core 6). I've used WebOptimizer in the past, I've created single-file applications in the past... I just can't get them to work together. If I use the bundler like:

```
// Add the bundler...
builder.Services.AddWebOptimizer(pipeline =>
{
    pipeline.AddJavaScriptBundle("~/js/myBundle.js","js/views/js1.js", "js/views/js2.js", "js/main.js");
});
```

And the file provider is:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(
        assembly: Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
        baseNamespace: "MyApp.wwwroot"),
})
```

And in the csproj file I have:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="wwwroot\**" ExcludeFromSingleFile="false">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory> Always </CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="wwwroot\**\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Each time a page tries to load the bundle I get a warning:

*warn: WebOptimizer.AssetBuilder[1005]
File '/js/myBundle.js' not found. Passing on to next middleware.*

All the other resources under wwwroot are found in the EmbeddedFileProvider route, just not the ones put in the pipeline by WebOptimizer. It seems like it's close...I just can't find the right route.

Comment: As I noted below, the app does compress and work as a single-file app. If I manually minify/bundle and put the resultant file in wwwroot/js, then build the app, everything works. It's when WebOptimizer does the runtime minify/bundle that the routing mismatch seems to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure set the `EnableCompressionInSingleFile` property to `true`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    //......
    <EnableCompressionInSingleFile>true</EnableCompressionInSingleFile>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli#compress-assemblies-in-single-file-apps

Comment: Yep it is, and it's getting compressed by about 50%...so that's cool. But the problem still exists. If I manually minify and bundle the js, put it in wwwroot and then build it, the min.js file is found no problem. It's when WebOptimizer does the run-time minify/bundle that it isn't on the correct route. Either WebOptimizer puts it in the wrong place or EmbeddedFileProvider looks for it in the wrong place.

Comment: Hi @WirelessG, I reproduce the issue by using your code and add the `EnableCompressionInSingleFile` to resolve it. Maybe you need share your code to a repo without sharing your personal data.